# SyntaxError: Function statements must have a name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below (very) short piece of code I'm trying to get to work. There's more to it than this, but this is the part I can't get to work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    getEvents: function() {
        $.getJSON('/wp-json/routename/v1/shows/fri', function(data) {
            var events = data;
        });
    }
    getEvents();
    console.log(events);
});
```

All I get back when running this in console is "SyntaxError: Function statements must have a name.". I tried simply defining the function as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getEvents() {
        $.getJSON('/wp-json/routename/v1/shows/fri', function(data) {
            var events = data;
        });
    }
    getEvents();
    console.log(events);
});
```

Then I get a message in console stating "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: events".

If I simply define events and add the JSON to it (i.e. events = [{"name":"TEST"}]; ) instead of trying to get events populated via a JSON call, it works like a charm.

What am I doing wrong here?
Much appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to define `getEvents` if you're only calling it just once in that scope.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('/wp-json/routename/v1/shows/fri', function(data) {
        var events = data;
        console.log(events);
    });
});
```

And you were trying to log `events` before it was available (since the ajax call is asynchronous).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you're making random attempts at adding extra syntax, but it looks like all you're trying to do is this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('/wp-json/routename/v1/shows/fri', function(data) {
        var events = data;
        console.log(events);
    });
});
```

In the first attempt you were trying to define a function like an object, which didn't really make sense.  In the second attempt you were trying to use a local function variable outside of that function, which you can't do.  (You were also trying to use it before it was being set, which you also can't do.)